# Universal App - iPad not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I have build an universal application which works perfectly in iPhone Simulator. But the application crashes in iPad simulator. The execution does not enter in to the AppDelegate of the iPad itself. While the application is compiled in iPad, it throws the error:

```
2011-01-31 14:52:51.330 MassStorage[1751:207] *** -[NSCFArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x680fbe0
2011-01-31 14:52:51.335 MassStorage[1751:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArraysortedArrayUsingComparator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x680fbe0'
2011-01-31 14:52:51.336 MassStorage[1751:207] Stack: (
45590608,
46748460,
45599323,
45061750,
45058546,
26736,
21965,
3682181,
3675039,
3735534,
3731264,
3739449,
3714977,
5049482,
41527574,
41526821,
41470418,
41469746,
3069270,
3095870,
3077367,
3109336,
54583676,
44869788,
44865704,
3068449,
3101554,
55758,
10521
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Can anybody help me??? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run your iPad simulator with iOS version 3.2

sortedArrayUsingComparator: was introduced in iOS4.

If you must use sortedArrayUsingComparator: and there is no way to do the same thing with other methods you need to set your deployment target to iOS 4.0